# Functor instance of generic functors

Tags: haskell

```
data Id a = Id a
data Const a b = Const a
```

the functor instance of above is

```
instance Functor Id where
  fmap f (Id x ) = Id (f x )
instance Functor (Const a) where
  fmap f (Const x ) = Const x
```

`f` somehow did not apply in the `const`, `const (f x)` I am confusing about how it work because at least it involves one variable.

Comment: The `f` function indeed apply to `x` of `const (f x)`, e.g. `const ((+1) 1) 0 = 2`, why `f` did not apply in the `const`?

Comment: @assembly.jc i don't know either! check the answer below maybe you can understant

Comment: do u means `Const` not `const` function in [`Prelude`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:const)?

Comment: @assembly.jc Yes

Answer (score 3):

Suppose we have `f :: Bool -> Int` and

```
x :: Const String Bool
x = Const "some string here"
```

Now, `fmap f x` must have type `Const String Int`, and the only reasonable choice for its result `y` is

```
y :: Const String Int
y = Const "some string here"
```

Note how `x` and `y` are roughly the same value, but they belong to distinct types. Further, in order to compute `y` we do not have to use `f` in any way, since `x` does not have any `Bool` inside, and `y` does not have any `Int` inside. `f` is then irrelevant.

Note that type `Const a b` is isomorphic to `a`, whatever type `b` is. That's why it is named `Const`: it does not really use its second argument. Its second argument still matters since it causes `Const a b` and `Const a b'` to be distinct types, even if both are isomorphic to `a`.

Comment: yes that make sense, but i search on hoogle of id and it is id:: a->a, eg: id x = x.    const in hoogle is const::a->b->a and eg:: const 42"hello = 42. so these two are both not affect the value. what i confuse is if id doesn't change it but f apply, so as const.

Comment: @littlefish Your code does not use `const`. It defines a type named `Const`, but that's an independent thing to function `const`. There is a loose similarity, in that `const x y` returns `x` and discards `y`, while `Const a b` is a type having a value of type `a` inside, ignoring type parameter `b`. Apart from this, there is no connection between function `const` and type constructor `Const`.

Comment: oh, sorry about my mistake, why f won't apply to a type a then

Comment: @littlefish Because `f :: b->b'` so it can't be applied to type `a`. In my example above, `a=String`, `b=Bool`, `b'=Int`. So, we can't really apply `f :: Bool->Int` to `"some string here"` (of type `String`)  in a meaningful way -- how would you do that?

Comment: I understand NOW! thank you so much. forgot to look at the signature of f

Answer (score 0):

`Const` instance just ignores the `f` function and doesn't change its value. `Id` instance applies `f` function to its value and returns new `Id` with new value.